# A case when Slick uses more connections than threads

Tags: scala, relational-database, slick

I am puzzled with this statement from Slick documentation:

> Slick will use more connections than there are threads in the pool when sequencing non-database actions inside a transaction.

Does this mean that Slick opens a transaction and then uses different database connections (in different threads) to perform actions inside that transaction? Do I get it right? I never thought it is possible to keep a transaction open among several connections.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Seems I was wrong in my understanding.

Let's say the Slick thread pool size is 1. And we have a transaction 1, which runs two queries A and B.

First, Slick opens a connection 1, runs a query A using occupying the single thread in the thread pool. At the same time a transaction 2 is queued having a single query C to run. As all the threads are occupied, query C is put into the queue.

Meanwhile query A finishes and some Scala code runs asynchronously to process results (using another thread pool). The processing thread is returned to the Slick thread pool. But as transaction 1 is still running the database connection 1 is still in use.

So when query C is run, Slick sees that there are no free connections, and therefore creates a new database connection 2 to run it. This is exactly that situation, which is mentioned in the docs - we have 2 open connections, while the thread pool size is only 1.

That's is why the default connection pool settings are like this:

- `minConnections` by default equals to `numThreads`
- `maxConnections` by default equals to `numThreads * 5`

So if you don't run several queries in a transaction, then Slick should never open more connections than there are threads.